# Has anyone hooked up PySide to Blender?

Tags: python

I'm looking to make some custom gui elements. Has anyone had success using pyside to use Qt to communicate with Blender?

Comment: If it is meant as a part of Blender script/plugin why not use the Blender GUI? Surely this should integrate better.

Comment: I have my reasons. I'm making an exporter that links to a webservice, not a file. I don't think it's unreasonable that I would want additional gui elements.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least a video showing someone compiled PyQt into Blender:

http://vimeo.com/86398593

And a facebook post:

https://www.facebook.com/cgtutorials/posts/521688517904188?stream_ref=10

So it seems possible, at least with a modified Blender binary.

Comment: Watching this video is one of the inspirations for asking this question.

Comment: It's definitely a missing feature for me too

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to get PySide working inside Blender, but i have had trouble getting PySide working correctly in python 3.4 standalone, so i gave up on PySide and moved to PyQt4.

First of all, i have it working on mac OSX 10.8 with blender 2.71. but i would say the process below would be almost the same on linux, but for windows may be easier, as you can download QT4 and PyQT4 binaries

i would suggest setting up a Virtual environment, as i previously had issues with different versions of python running on my machine, and it mucked up the install path, and version of python used to compile PyQt.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

You need to make sure you install PyQT with the exact version of python that blender is using (2.71 uses 3.4, 2.70 uses 3.3)

I used the following versions.

- Python 3.4.1
- Qt 4.8.6
- pyQT 4.11.1

Once you have the correct python version, and virtualenv set up and working this is the code i use inside blender to open a PyQT window.

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('*venv directory* /py3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages')
import bpy
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 

class ExampleQtWindow(QtGui.QDialog): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super(ExampleQtWindow, self).__init__() 
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self) 
        self.buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout() 
        self.CreateButton = QtGui.QPushButton("print info") 
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.CreateButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.testCommand) 
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.CreateButton) 
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout) 

    def testCommand(self): 
        print(bpy.data.objects) 


# register class stuff 
class PyQtEvent(): 
    _timer = None 
    _window = None 

    def execute(self): 
        self._application = QtGui.QApplication.instance() 
        if self._application is None: 
            self._application = QtGui.QApplication(['']) 
            self._eventLoop = QtCore.QEventLoop() 
            self.window = ExampleQtWindow() 
            self.window.show() 

print("running in background") 
new_window = PyQtEvent() 
new_window.execute()
```