# Is anyone using MySQL in Blender / python

Tags: python

For a project I'm thinking on using a small database to store information on objects, then extract this information with a Python script. The Python script then would use this data for generating 3D (geometric) objects. The database would function for (intermediate) storing info with an easy programmable update interface (HTML, PHP).

Searching for the three components (Blender, the underlying Python, MySQL) I do run into a myriad of possibilities and especially different versions.

Before embarking I would like to know if somebody has already done something similar and could brief me on my journey. Or point me to similar ideas?

Thanks for reading and answering!

Regards,
Wim.

Comment: Hi. This site works better for specific problems, whereas what you're asking is quite broad. If you are looking for more of a discussion I recommend creating a thread on [blenderartists](http://blenderartists.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your objects have a ton of data points, a DB as beefy as mySQL would likely be overkill. A '**sql lite**' version might be more effective.

Google: *mysql lite python*   where you'll find many possibilities, including frontends.

RE Frontends, see also [Has anyone hooked up PySide to Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/has-anyone-hooked-up-pyside-to-blender?rq=1)