# How to import PySide into Blender?

Tags: python, scripting

I have been trying to import PySide into Blender to make some custom gui elements. I've searched several sites and found answers like [How to import PyQt into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43899/how-to-import-pyqt-into-blender) and [Has anyone hooked up PySide to Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/has-anyone-hooked-up-pyside-to-blender), but I haven't found any solution about it.

I've managed to import PyQt5 in Blender and to work correctly. However, when I tried to import PySide into Blender, it seems to work but then it gives problems when I try to create gui elements, because when I run the script into Blender, Blender crashes.

I'm using the following versions:

- Python 3.6.3
- PySide2
- Blender 2.79

How can I get PySide2 to work properly within Blender?