# PySide Tool In Blender

Tags: python

I'm new to the Blender community. My background has primarily been in Maya and 3ds Max. I'm looking to port some tools over to Blender. However I have failed to find any information regarding how to build a PySide interface and attach it to the Blender window. So when blender closes or minimizes the PySide tool goes with it. Secondly, I've read numerous times people who have created a PySide tool mentioning that it's a modal dialog and blocking. Is this all true and still relevant in the latest version of Blender?

I hope the modal, blocking dialog is not true. For an app that has so much promise, this would be enough of a deterrent to not implement Blender into our pipeline which is heavily tool driven in order to integrate with Shotgun. I can't imagine innovative app like Blender not sorting an issue like this out.

Thanks everyone im looking forward to hearing back.

Comment: This discussion might help... https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8327/has-anyone-hooked-up-pyside-to-blender